# How to add a variable to count the number of times the script has been called?

Tags: shell

I am writing a script to add data to a file after the script has been run.
Since I need to mail the data forward, I need a variable to assign the number of times the script has been called.

I am using a temp file which stores the value of count. Every time the script is called the variable temp is called, the value incremented and stored in count. The incremented value is than stored back to the temp.

```
count=$((temp + 1))
echo $count > temp
printf "%d\t%10s\t" "$count" "$datet" >> table
```

this is the code i'm using, but temp is not increasing...?

Comment: You are writing a variable into a file. To let the script know what was the value on the previous execution, you have to read the file. Use for example `temp=$(cat temp)` before everything.

Comment: Is the old value of temp being loaded into the temp variable before the calculation?

Comment: yes, initially value of temp is 0, after the script runs it increments to 1. But doesn't change after that. The value remains 1 no matter how many times I run the script. @simon

Comment: @fedorqui So you're saying something like $[$(cat temp) +1] or just iniialize another variable in the script before using to increment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the previous value before anything else:

```
temp=$(cat temp)
count=$((temp + 1))
echo "$count" > temp
printf "%d\t%10s\t" "$count" "$datet" >> table
```

#### Test

```
$ echo "0" > temp
$ ./a
$ cat temp 
1
$ ./a
$ cat temp 
2
```

Comment: Kind of what I was referring to. The temp value wasn't being set beforehand so therefore temp was always equal to 0 (or null / nothing) before the calculation. What fedorqui is doing is loading the old value first.

Comment: to suppress an error the first time add `if [ ! -f temp ]; then
 echo "0">temp;
fi`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `cat temp` to get the value inside the file `temp`.

But I would suggest to use a variable for the temporary file for better code readeablility:

```
TMP=/tmp/counter
if [ ! -f $TMP ]; then echo "0">$TMP; fi
count=$(($(cat $TMP) + 1))
echo $count > $TMP
printf "%d\t%10s\t" "$count" >> /tmp/somelogfile
```

Or in one line, if you don't need the count in a variable:

```
echo "$(($(cat $TMP) + 1))">$TMP
```

Then you can later use:

```
echo $(cat $TMP)
```